# No password required from localhost even though using md5

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql version 13.

My pg_hba.conf looks like this:

```
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
  host all      all   all     md5
```

inspite of that, I can connect from local host without a password.

When I look at table pg_hba_file_rules, I see this:

```
line_number | type  |   database    | user_name |  address  |                 netmask                 | auth_method | options | error
-------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------
          88 | local | {all}         | {all}     |           |                                         | trust       |         |
          90 | host  | {all}         | {all}     | 127.0.0.1 | 255.255.255.255                         | trust       |         |
          92 | host  | {all}         | {all}     | ::1       | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | trust       |         |
          95 | local | {replication} | {all}     |           |                                         | trust       |         |
          96 | host  | {replication} | {all}     | 127.0.0.1 | 255.255.255.255                         | trust       |         |
          97 | host  | {replication} | {all}     | ::1       | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | trust       |         |
          99 | host  | {all}         | {all}     | all       |                                         | md5         |         |
```

I have another postgres, with the same pg_hba.conf settings, but there I see this:

```
 line_number | type  |   database    |    user_name    | address | netmask | auth_method | options | error
-------------+-------+---------------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+-------
           1 | host  | {all}         | {repmgrdba}     | 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | md5         |         |
           2 | host  | {repmgr}      | {repmgrdba}     | 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | md5         |         |
           3 | host  | {repmgr}      | {repmgrdba}     | ::      | ::      | md5         |         |
           4 | host  | {replication} | {repmgrdba}     | 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | md5         |         |
           5 | host  | {replication} | {repmgrdba}     | ::      | ::      | md5         |         |
           8 | host  | {all}         | {all}           | 0.0.0.0 | 0.0.0.0 | md5         |         |
           9 | host  | {all}         | {all}           | ::      | ::      | md5         |         |
          10 | local | {all}         | {all}           |         |         | md5         |         |
```

Where are the additional settings then that make up for the difference..?

Comment: The rules come exclusively from `pg_hba.conf`. If they are different, you didn't reload (or reloading caused an error).

Comment: After changing the config file, you need to restart/reload the server for it to take effect.

Comment: I already used "SELECT pg_reload_conf();" even though both postgres came with the same configuration (nothing I changed). Still the "pg_hba_file_rules" shows the same differences between the two databases.

Comment: From here [pg_hba_file_rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/view-pg-hba-file-rules.html)"Note that this view reports on the current contents of the file, not on what was last loaded by the server."  Also show your complete `pg_hba.conf` file as it is more then `host all all  all md5 ` and from the view `host  all  all 127.0.0.1 trust` comes first. In `pg_hba.conf` first match wins which would mean the `trust` line is taking precedence.